# Multiply two fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two different models

```
class Part(models.Model):
    partno = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    tax = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):

    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    po_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'd like to multiply `price` from Part with `po_quantity` and result show in the `amount`. e.g

amount = price * po_quantity

Can someone assist me to solve this?

Comment: Since `amount` fully depends on the `price` and the `po_quantity`, you better use a property for this. Otherwise you introduce *data duplication*.

Answer (score 1):

Since `amount` fully depends on the `price` and the `po_quantity`, you better use a property for this. Otherwise you introduce *data duplication*. You thus can implement this as:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    po_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def amount(self):
        return self.po_quantity * self.part.price
```

If you need to use the `amount` when filtering, you can use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) instead, and define this for example in a `Manager`:

```
from django.db.models import F

class PurchaseOrderManager(models.Manager):
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            amount=F('po_quantity') * F('part__price')
        )


class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    po_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PurchaseOrderManager()
```